# Upgrade to IE 11 successful, but still at IE 9

Tags: windows-7, updates, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

For several months now I have been trying to upgrade IE 9 to IE 11 on my Windows 7 system.

The upgrade to 11 seems to go fine (based on IE11_main.log), but IE 9 comes up when I click on the IE icon.

Are there any tips or an answer to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing IE from Programs and Features and then re-add it and see what happens?

Comment: Neither IE9 or IE11 show on the "Programs and Features" window.  IE11 shows up on "Windows Features" and is checked.

Comment: You could uncheck it, in Windows Feature  let it complete, reboot, come back and recheck that IE11 , reboot again, then test again.  Why ?  Because the IE11 component store is likely in existance if the IE11 is shown there.  Turning it "on and off" just re-links it back into the system, And possibly tosses in some regitry items,  which could correct the problem.  If it does not fix it, you might want to check more of the system files by running >SFC /scannow in the command prompt as an admin

Comment: Psycogeek - I tried what you mentioned (not the SFC command) and it really didn't change anything.  But I did check to see how many copies of IEXPLORE.EXE I had on my disk.  I found 79 files taking up 60 MB!  Most were in the Windows\winsxs directory.  Some research I did on that showed this is where Windows updates are kept and how to clean it up.  Once I did that, IE 11 was on my system!!! WooHoo!  Thanks to you and SuperUser.com for getting me to look at the problem a little closer!  SOLVED!!!

Answer (score 1):

Psycogeek - I tried what you mentioned (not the SFC command) and it really didn't change anything. But I did check to see how many copies of IEXPLORE.EXE I had on my disk. I found 79 files taking up 60 MB! Most were in the Windows\winsxs directory. Some research I did on that showed this is where Windows updates are kept and how to clean it up. Once I did that, IE 11 was on my system!!! WooHoo! Thanks to you and SuperUser.com for getting me to look at the problem a little closer! SOLVED!!!